# Need to pass a ds(data structure) when Http server is being started, and to make that ds global across controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So,

Here is the code setup.

There is a driver application, which starts the HTTP server(ASP.NET core Web API project).

> The method called by driver application for starting HTTP server is
>   this:

```
public class Http_Server
    {

        public static ConcurrentQueue<Object> cq = new ConcurrentQueue<Object>();

        public static void InitHttpServer(ConcurrentQueue<Object> queue)
        { 
            cq = queue;
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

> Controller Action Task:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("XYZ")]
        public virtual IActionResult AddXYZ([FromBody]List<Resourcemembers> resourcemembers)
        {
            //add something to ds 
            Http_Server.cq.Enqueue(new object());

            //respond back
            return new ObjectResult(example);
        }
```

The data structure(a concurrent queue) being passed is to be made visible at controller level(like a global variable accessible across all controllers).

Is it fine to make the ds a static variable and access it across controllers?

Or Is there a way to pass this ds across to different layers?

Comment: I am not well versed in concurrent queues, but, why don't you make this DS a service and use DI in ASP.NET Core to make it available to the controllers. I am thinking you need to make whatever DS this is into a singleton service.

Comment: thanks! looks better this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my go at a better solution for this. What you are trying to do doesn't seem like the best way to approach this.

First, you want to enable caching in the application by calling the `AddMemoryCache` in the application `StartUp.ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    ...
}
```

Then, you want to use the cache. Something like this should get you going in the right direction.

```
public class XYZController : Controller {
    private IMemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private const string xyzCacheKey = "XYZ";

    public XYZController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    [HttpPost("XYZ")]
    public IActionResult AddXYZ([FromBody]ResourceMember[] resourceMembers)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue(xyzCacheKey, out ConcurrentQueue<Object> xyz))
            {
                xyz = new ConcurrentQueue<Object>();
                _memoryCache.Set(xyzCacheKey, xyz, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                {
                    SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0)
                });
            }
            xyz.Enqueue(resourceMembers);

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex);
        }
    }
}

public class ResourceMember { }
```

What this does is allow you to use a [Memory Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory) to hold your object(s), and what ever you `Enqueue` in the `ConcurrentQueue` object, should you stay with that as your main object within the Cache. Now, you can cache any object type in the `MemoryCache`, and pull the value when you need to based on the key you gave it when you added it to the cache. In the case above, I created a const named `xyzCacheKey` with a string value of XYZ to use as the key.

That static global variable thing you are trying is just not... good.

If this doesn't help, let me know in a comment, I will delete the answer.

Good luck!